# how to initiate a dynamic array in struct with shared memory C -language

Tags: c, linux, shared

I would to ask you, how initiate array in struct for size from keyboard(argv)  with shared memory, I can't use malloc, because it initiate's privat or something like that.

For example piece of code

> Struct with array which I want initiate

```
struct data
{
  char txt[size from keyboard];
};
```

How to resize this array, remembering that we will use shared memory IPCV?

Thanks form your help :)

edit:

so if I had one more variable in struct, Can I do it like this?

```
struct data
{
   int counter; 
   char *text;
}*shared data;

int shmid

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int m = atoi(argv[1]) /* number of slots*/ 
  int n = atoi(argv[2]) /*size of txt */

  shmid = shmget(12345, m * n * sizeof(struct my_data), IPC_CREAT|)600|IPc_EXCL)); 

shared_data = (struct data*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

/*So now Can I write to txt??? */


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `txt` from `char[]` to `char*`, and then use `shm_open()` and `mmap()` to allocate shared memory once you know the desired size.

```c
typedef struct data
{
  char *txt;
} data;

data d;
int shm_fd = shm_open("name", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
d.txt = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
...
munmap(d.txt, size);
shm_unlink("name");
```

Comment: Is it possible to it in IPCV? I ask, because shm_open and mmap are POSIX

Comment: @Roundstic I don't know what IPCV is

Comment: linux System V IPC

Comment: [According to this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html), System V has another API for shared memory, so just replace `shm_open()`/`mmap()`/`munmap()`/`shm_unlink()` in my example with [`shmget()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html)/[`shmat()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html)/[`shmdt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmdt.2.html)/[`shmctl()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html) instead.